# BASE64DecoderStream to Document(org.w3c.dom.Document)

Tags: base64, jakarta-mail, domdocument

I'm getting the server e-mail an attached file (XML) which is an InputStream and inside contains a BASE64DecoderStream, and would like to turn this into a BASE64DecoderStream Document (org.w3c.dom.Document) for me to do research in XML I'm getting.

Anyone know how to turn?

Already I am very grateful!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html).  Create an [org.xml.sax.InputSource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/InputSource.html) wrapping the InputStream you get from the getContent() method,
then use the DocumentBuilder.parse() method.  You'll find more details about the JAXP (javax.xml) API in the javadocs.